# optimizing segregated list organization for malloc implementation

Tags: c, data-structures, linked-list, malloc, binary-search-tree

I'm working on the `cs:app malloc lab` (I'm not looking for implemented answers, just high level processes), which if you're not familiar, asks for an implementation of `malloc()`.

I have heap blocks with size, status `in_use`, and a pointer to the next/previous free block (if the block is not alloc'ed), which lends itself best to a *linked list* of free blocks (explicit free list). 
Since we've been given that the max size for our heap is 2^32, I'm thinking about switching this to a *segregated list* in a BST, where the root node defines the size class and has a pointer to its free list (e.g. an object of size 2^n gets stored in a node's list where `node->class == n`).

Intuition tells me using an AVL tree would speed up look-up for free blocks and insertion of new size classes, and using segregated lists helps mitigate fragmentation, but I'm still relatively new to thinking about these kinds of systems. Can someone confirm/deny my reasoning? (hope this isn't too vague a question!)

Comment: You'd probably learn more if you spent a little time researching the problem.  Searching for "memory manager design" or "custom memory manager" provides a lot of good articles that discuss the benefits and drawbacks of many different designs. "Best" is, at best, a rather nebulous concept. Are you trying to reduce fragmentation? Increase speed? Do you want a close to constant allocation time, or are you okay with periodic delays as the heap is compacted? There are many things to consider. As written, your question is way too broad to provide a meaningful answer.

Comment: thanks for the input @JimMischel! I should probably edit my initial question since i wasn't really asking for the ""best"" algorithm so much as asking whether using a BST (avl) to organize my segregated lists was a feasible idea.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
start with two pointers.  
#define SIZE_OF_HEAP = &endHeap - &Heap;
freePtr = &Heap; 
Heap = NULL;  // at start, the first linked list entry has no following entry
usedPtr = NULL;

with each allocation, insert the address into the usedPtr list
update the freePtr list to 'skip around' the allocated block

with each free, remove the block info from the userPtr list
insert the block info into the freePtr list (by address magnitude)
check if any two freePtr blocks are adjacent
if adjacent, the merge into a single block

The heap processing should have an 'initial' state, for
any initialization 
(like setting the initial values of the usedPtr and freePtr 
     linked list head values  
     then change state to 'ready')

be sure to handle cases such as when the address passed to free() is not on the usedPtr linked list

be sure to handle cases such as when there is no freePtr block large enough to accommodate the requested block size.

Note: these linked lists, other than the head pointers, 
     are actually embedded in the heap at the beginning of each block. 
Should also keep a small buffer at the end of each allocated block 
set it to some known value, like '0xdead' or the address of the block
so can check to see if the heap has been corrupted

effectively this results in two linked lists, 
between the two linked lists, all of the heap is covered.

 note: the address passed back to the caller 
 is actually the address past the end of the linked list entry for the block.  
 SO an actual allocation is slightly larger than what the user requested.

be sure each returned address to the user is on a 32/64 bit boundary.
```

Comment: there are other methods, such as pre-allocating arrays of different sized blocks where each block indicates if it is allocated or not.   Such a method may need some 'tweaking' as to the size of the blocks and the size of the arrays. which is easiest handled by a separate file that contains the details.  This separate file would be modified by the sysAdmin, then the system rebooted

Comment: even using the suggested method, two linked lists, there is also the decision on how to pick a block.  there are two main methods of selection.  1) first fit and 2) best fit.  1 is quicker, but can result in more fragmentation  2) is slower, but results in less fragmentation and is more likely to have room available when a new allocation is requested.

Comment: a third method is the user gets a number of an entry into a table, where that entry points to the actual data.  Then a background process can perform garbage collection.  However, this requires an extra step by the user, that they may easily fumble.